Do the decoupling capacitors act as capacitive load to the opamp which is used to make a virtual gorund?

Source: https://tangentsoft.com/elec/vgrounds.html
I am trying to design a circuit using a single battery as shown in the image above, I am worried that all the decoupling capacitors that will go from V+ and V- to the VGND will act as a load to the opamp (OPA in the image) and cause it to oscillate.
My circuit will have 5 opamps operating off this +V, -V and VGD which will each have two bypass capacitors going from V+ to VGND and V- to VGND, so in total 10 bypass capacitors of 10uF value each.
Q1 Will those decoupling capacitors act as a load to the opamp?

Yes, they will act as a load and the 1kΩ resistor will make things worse. Typically at least 10x worse. As you can see, typically it will oscillate merrily. you won't see much of that at the fake ground with 10uF caps on there, but it will manifest in other ways including power consumption and poor "DC" stability since the op-amp will likely be railing.
If you simply close the feedback around the op-amp and use 100Ω rather than 1kΩ to the artificial ground you'll get stability but degraded performance (the fake ground will change voltage with loading).
If you provide two feedback paths (for AC and DC) you get a bit of both, but the fake ground will still not be perfect under rapid changes in current.

The second one is a bit underdamped for my taste, but one can play around with values and get something that suits all the requirements.
Here it is with different values and also the second option I mentioned above, of just the series resistor with feedback around the op-amp. The output changes by the load current * 100Ω or 1mV due to the 1mA load change.


De-coupling caps are not an issue if you do things in the right way. A "virtual ground" like this is not the same as a "true ground" which you have with a real +/- split supply. It is merely a stable DC reference for your analogue circuits. If you treat it as such, you don't have a problem.
But first let's get the basic circuit sorted. This is a circuit which I have used many times with no issue.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note that C1 does not need to be large - there is almost no load current drawn from the junction of R1/R2. We do NOT need a second cap across R1, as we do not want transients on the supply (which should anyway be minimal because of C2) to be coupled onto the virtual ground). A bipolar op-amp with decent output current is advisable, though this of course depends on the application. When I have used this circuit, stability has never been an issue and no output resistor has been necessary - in fact you don't want that as it really degrades the impedance of Vsplit. The opamp is simply buffering a stable DC voltage. Nothing unusual or special is happening, from its point of view, so long as we use it within its limits.
(I would agree that a specialist virtual ground chip is a slight improvement, but if you are using opamps anyway and havge a spare stage, this is really just as good.)
A couple of caveats:

I'm talking audio frequency here. If you are dealing with RF, you would need at least a different opamp (and possibly a whole different approach ...)
The important part: in the "target" circuit, do not decouple from +V/0V to the virtual ground. Place your decoupling caps between +V and 0V. The virtual ground should not be used as a return path for noise or interference on the supplies. (In fact there those who would even take this approach on a conventional circuit with true split supplies, but that is another topic.)
With an NE5532, you can sink/source a maximum of 10 mA. Take this into account when designing. For most analogue audio battery powered devices, which is where this seems to crop up, this is OK.
If you are talking about a headphone amp, some care is needed. It would be ideal if you could drive the two headphone sides independently in "bridge" mode, however this is generally impossible without using a non-standard connector. Given the 10 mA limitation, you can drive a peak voltage of 3V into a single 300 Ω, but with stereo this becomes 1.5 V, a little low for a +/-2.5 V supply. So it depends what impedance cans you want to use. If a single 5532 is not adequate, I would probably experiment with something like a push-pull output (with discrete transistors) or a higher current buffer IC as mentioned in your link.



Stability of an opamp with a capacitive load depends on:

Load capacitance and ESR

Opamp's output impedance and bandwidth


Load capacitance adds a pole, which adds phase lag and reduces phase margin, but ESR adds a zero which cancels this pole.
The most problematic case is a low capacitance value and low ESR, which you'd encounter with several 100nF caps used as decoupling (red). General purpose electrolytic caps with higher value and high ESR (blue) tend to work much better. Adding a resistor at the output of the opamp will increase its output impedance which may (or not) make things more stable.
The opamp's input voltage should be filtered as any noise on it will be replicated on the output, so the opamp will attempt to drive the caps with it.
A low value isolation resistor (R8) can be effective.



Will those decoupling capacitors act as a load to the op-amp?

Yes they will and, your concerns are valid. It would be probably better to use a voltage regulator instead of an op-amp because they are designed to have capacitive loads.
However, the 1 kΩ output resistor is usually sufficient to keep the op-amp stable under moderate capacitive loading. Maybe try simulating it and trying different op-amps to see what is most suitable.

Here's what I like to use for regulated bias voltages:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
C1 gives you high frequency feedback, stabilizing the circuit against the phase lag due to the load capacitance. R2 can be small, an ohm or a few. If R1>>R2 and R1*C1=4*R2*C2, the circuit is critically damped.
